# $_POST['variable'] without &nbsp;

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a working select that is generated by PHP.

Code:

```
echo "<form method='post'><select name='selectid'>";
$result_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DB.Table");
  while($row_select = mysql_fetch_array($result_select))
    {
        echo "<option "; 
        if ($row['Value'] == $row_select['Value'] ) echo 'selected';
        echo ">{$row_select['Value']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row_select['Value']}
        </option>";
    }
echo "</select></form>";
```

Now the problem is, I want to $_POST the selected value from select. It is  working, too. But I want to get the string without &nbsp

I have tried:

```
$text_description="&nbsp;Helloworld!&nbsp;";
$text_description = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $text_description);
echo $text_description;
```

And it's working. But when I replace

```
 $text_description="&nbsp;Helloworld!&nbsp;";
```

to

```
 $text_description=$_POST['selectid'];
```

it's not working any more.

Comment: (As per this, and your previous question, we prefer posts not to contain "help me please" and similar, especially in the title. This is widely regarded as distracting and/or begging, and can make it less likely that you get the answer you need. Just write detailed posts with minimal embellishment - it seems fine now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a value attribute to your options:

```
echo "<form method='post'><select name='selectid'>";
$result_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DB.Table");
  while($row_select = mysql_fetch_array($result_select))
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row_select['Value']}'"; 
        if ($row['Value'] == $row_select['Value'] ) echo 'selected';
        echo ">{$row_select['Value']}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row_select['Value']}
        </option>";
    }
echo "</select></form>";
```

Comment: Yes, though it might be worth pointing out to the OP their code is susceptible to XSS. A templating library, or at least not trapping everything in `echo` statements, will help.

Comment: Thanks reply! The problem is not to get the value from the select, the problem is to get it just like "somevale1somevalue2", but i get "somevalue1    somevalue2". And this hidden whitespaces are in browser "somevalue1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;somevalue2".

Comment: then just add "somevale1somevalue2" inside the value="" attribute!

Comment: Thanks A lot, @SzabolcsPáll